# remove a job form cluster

Tags: jobs, job-scheduling, condor

I am on Linux VM. I know there is the command  `condor_submit hello.submit` that will  submit a job to cluster. However if I want to remove the jobs submitted. Is there a way? I created a user first using the command: `sudo adduser user2` then logged in to user2 with command `su user2` to then submit a job using the code above. How can I "unsubmit"/remove it?

Answer (score 0):

the `condor_rm` command is what you are looking for.  It takes either the job id that `condor_submit` printed out, or `-a` for all jobs, or if you are root, the name of the user whose jobs you want to remove.